# How to extract fitted data from normal probability density function

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution, probability-density

If I fit a uni-variate data with normal distribution, how can i get back the fitted values in MATLAB.
I am using this simple example

```
load hospital % data
x = hospital.Weight;
[mu sigma]=normfit(x) %normal fitting
%To visualize the pdf
xval=min(x):0.1:max(x)
yval=normpdf(xval,mu,sigma)
plot(xval,yval)
```

yval is giving the probabilities of xval values. Now, If I would like to extract the fitted values of 'x' after approximating it with the above normal distribution, how do I do that?. As can be seen in the picture the y-axis values are the pdf and lies between 0 and 1, however I want the corresponding fitted values from the data that follows normal distribution.

[image]

Would the fitted values be x_fitted = yval*sigma + mu? !I think I am missing some basic maths here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`normfit` simply gives you the `mu` and `sigma` of the fitted normal pdf. From those you build that pdf with `normpdf`. So the desired `y` values for your input `x` would be

```
y = normpdf(x,mu,sigma)
```

which you could plot with

```
hold on
plot(x,y,'ro')
```

[image]

Note that, with this procedure, the data lie exactly on the normal pdf, even if those data do not actually follow a normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks. The values of y is in the range of [0,1] because it is probability, how can we translate them so it can have magnitude corresponding original data x? In my above example mu=154 and sigma=26.57 but 0<=y<=1

Comment: You already have tha magnitude of the original data. I don't see how you could obtain another magnitude for the fitted data, if that's what you want; I'm not really sure it would even make sense